# Android new File(path)

Tags: android

Why f is not a file? What could possibly cause this?

```
    String currentPhotoPath = "file:/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/someFileName.jpg";

    ...

    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    if (f == null || !f.isFile()) {
        // This gets executed
    }
```

Comment: File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg"); try your path be like that feed me back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

did you try this?

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures";
String fileName = "someFileName.jpg";

File f = new File(filePath,filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `File` instances can be directories or nonexisting files as well. See [the reference of `isFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) for details on the checks it performs.

---

In your case, however, I think the main issue is that you're initializing the `File` instance with an URI, but use the constructor for actual path. You could either use the constructor with a filename, or with the [constructor using `URI` objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29).

Comment: How comes they do it this way here?  http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Did you validate that it works? The actual style of paths is not defined in the docs, as it may be platform dependent. Maybe Android allows paths to start with `file:`? At least in [OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java) the implementation is specific to the `FileSystem` used. So, if works the Android file system supports that I guess.

Comment: @chuckfinley I just looked into the download on the page you linked, and in there they use actual paths.